# Import json file during execution of unit test cases Create React App

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, tsconfig

While running unit test cases i want to be able to import a json file in my typescript code. The **tests** folder is excluded in the tsconfig.json file

The contents of the file are quite large and adding to a .ts file takes a long to load the file.

How do i include my sampleData.json only during the unit test case execution right now i get a compile error "**Cannot find module '../../sampleData.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension**..." even though the resolveJsonModule is set to true .

I do not want the json file be a part of the build

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How did you import your file ?

If this is by default import, ex:  `import bla from './bla.json'`. You have to add `"esModuleInterop": true` to your tsconfig.

Comment: I import using the "import statement" . Even after adding esModuleInterop still get the same issue 
The rootDir is set to src and __tests__ folder is a under the src directory which i exclude in my tsconfig.json file